# ASP.NET MVC: Render raw attribute value using TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Given the following:

```cs
public MvcHtmlString CreateHtml(HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(CreateInnerHtml());
}

public string CreateSomeInnerHtml()
{
    var li = new TagBuilder("li");
    var a = new TagBuilder("a");
    a.Attributes["href"] = "http://test:8080/${{var}}";
    li.InnerHtml += a;
    return li.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

How do I have the href value render in raw format?

I have tried

```
li.InnerHtml += htmlHelper.Raw(a);
```

and this, to try and decode it first... off sides... but worth a try.

```
a.Attributes["href"] = WebUtility.UrlDecode("http://test:8080/${{var}}");
```

and this, which really should render the whole thing without encodings...

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.Raw(CreateInnerHtml())).ToHtmlString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this little helper extension

```cs
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {

    internal static IHtmlString ToHtmlString(this TagBuilder tagBuilder, TagRenderMode renderMode) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(tagBuilder != null);
        return new HtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(renderMode));
    }

    public static IHtmlString CreateHtml(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
         return CreateSomeInnerHtml();
    }

    public static IHtmlString CreateSomeInnerHtml() {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.Attributes["href"] = "http://test:8080/${{var}}";
        li.InnerHtml += a;
        return li.ToHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal); // Note the use of the extenson here
    }
}
```

and use it like

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        @Html.CreateHtml()
    </ul>
</div>
```

which renders

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://test:8080/${{var}}"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```